# How can I move which part of my picture can be seen on my button?

Tags: html, css

how can I move the Hulu logo so that the word "Hulu" is more in the centre of the button? It is really confusing to me. I have absolutely no idea how too do it, and I apologise for not describing it very well. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am completely lost here and don't know what to do.

```css
body {
    padding: 50px;
    display: flex;
}

.netflix {
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 210px;
    width: 400px;
    border-style: none;
    outline-style: none;
    position:relative;
    background-image: url(netflix\ black\ logo.png);
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 3px;
}


.netflix:hover {
    transform:scale(1.03,1.03);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.hulu {
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 210px;
    width: 400px;
    background-image: url(https://productimages.nimbledeals.com/gift_card_skin/e8d26e937d5017929ab3338bbff8be9_1567801840833);
    background-size: cover;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    border-style: none;
    outline-style: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.hulu:hover {
    transform:scale(1.03,1.03);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(141, 105, 105, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

/*div {
    width: 310px;
    height: 169px; 
    background-image: url(netflix\ black\ logo.png);
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4;
    /*margin-right: 2px;*/
    /*margin-left: 5px;*/
    /*align-self: center;
}*/

/*p {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 176px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}*/
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>entertainment</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="shop.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form  action="https://netflix.com/" target="_blank">
        <button class="netflix">
            <!--div>
            </div>
            <p>visit netflix and stuff </p-->
        </button>
    </form>
    <form>
        <button class="hulu">
        </button>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)?

Comment: looks smack in the center.  what's the problem?

Comment: @rayhatfield thankyou!